# How to add level number to open graph post

Tags: android, facebook, facebook-opengraph

I am trying to use open graph to post something like:

```
User completed level 10 in THE GAME.
```

So far ive created my action and the object the action is acted on. Such as object = level action = complete.

Ive done this throught the open graph dashboard.

Currently i am using this code to post to a users time and it works:

```
 Bundle params = new Bundle();
params.putString("level", "http://samples.ogp.me/12344556");

Request request = new Request(
    Session.getActiveSession(),
    "me/game_name:completed",
    params,
    HttpMethod.POST
);
Response response = request.executeAndWait();
```

but the problem is it displays

```
User completeded Sample Level on THE GAME.
```

So i would like to know how can i customize the "Sample level" part to say completed Level 1" etc or whatever level the user is on?

Answer (score 0):

You need to create a OG object type "level". This object then has a property og:title that can have any title you want. Each level should have it's own Open Graph HTML page like this:

```
<head prefix="og: http://ogp.me/ns# fb: http://ogp.me/ns/fb# app_namespace: http://ogp.me/ns/fb/app_namespace#">
<meta property="fb:app_id" content="app_id" /> 
<meta property="og:type"   content="app_namespace:level" /> 
<meta property="og:url"    content="Put your own URL to the object here" /> 
<meta property="og:title"  content="Sample Level X" /> 
<meta property="og:image"  content="https://s-static.ak.fbcdn.net/images/devsite/attachment_blank.png" />
```

Each level should have it's own file with similar code in it. You'll use the URL of these files in a similar way like the http://samples.ogp.me/12344556 Facebook will fetch these objects and use them in your stories.

You can find more information here: [Facebook Open Graph - Defining an Object](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/technical-guides/opengraph/defining-an-object/)

Comment: You need to host it on some web server and refer to it via URL in the app. Facebook needs to be able to Lint it with their robot.

Comment: Got it! I am currently trying to use Heroku, but not sure how to upload the html file